# error in DDD, trying to find location of SEGFAULT

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ddd-debugger

whenever i try to run ddd ./draw2& to find where my seg fault occurs it doesnt work. i get this error

/home/dsk 13/ugrad/twendlan/C201/Assignment2/drafts/sysdeps/x86_64/strcmp.S: No such file or directory

I don't know how to get by this error, I'm using the same steps i used in the lab 5.

I included -g in my Makefile and I am entering the following command into the prompt...

ddd ./draw2&

then in ddd: program->run (int the arguments box i type ./input.valid.20.random ,which i placed in the same directory) so Why am I getting this error.